# Matrix from count of rows and columns of different excel file

Tags: r, matrix

I have 8 excel files. Each file has some number of rows and columns. I want to read 8 excel files in R studio and then create a matrix with number of rows and columns of each file. So the matrix should look like this

```
Name_of_Excel_file    CountOfRows    CountOfColumns
Excel1                100000          25
Excel2                50000           100
Excel3                10000           300
Excel4                3000            10
Excel5                80000           50
Excel6                50000           250
Excel7                40000           10
Excel8                20000           10
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: So the matrix should look like this

Lets say
Name of excel file Count of Rows Count of Columns
Excel1 10000 20
Excel2 5000 10
Excel3 1000 6
Excel4 1000000 40
Excel5 3000 6
Excel6 10000 50
Excel7 80000 55
Excel8 100000 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a probably long-winded way of getting your answer. I included commands for if you were actually loading the excel docs below:

```
# Load libraries:
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

# Read excel docs:
df1 <- data.frame(read_xlsx("df1.xlsx"))
df2 <- data.frame(read_xlsx("df2.xlsx"))
```

Then to simulate what you would do, I just created my own data frames that represent the excel docs to make it easy to reproduce:

```
# First "excel" doc:
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
y1 <- c(2,3,4,1)
df1 <- data.frame(x1,y1)

# Second excel doc:
x2 <- c(1,2,3,8)
y2 <- c(2,3,4,3)
df2 <- data.frame(x2,y2)

# Create variables for rows and cols each:
df1row <- nrow(df1)
df1col <- ncol(df1)
df2row <- nrow(df2)
df2col <- ncol(df2)

# Make data frames for each:
dfdims <- data.frame(df1row,
                     df1col)
df2dims <- data.frame(df2row,
                      df2col)

# Combine them:
all_dims <- data.frame(df1col, df1row, df2col, df2row)
all_dims

# Pivot so rows categorize docs:
pivot_dims <- all_dims %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:4,
               names_to = "Excel Doc",
               values_to = "Dims")
```

Should look like this when you print the pivot_dims function:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I just ran your code to understand how is it working. i got the error "Error in sys.source(codeFile , env, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data) : reached elapsed time limit" Could you please have a look and suggest ?

Comment: So the second part of my script (everything below where you read the xlsx files) is just a simulation of what you would do without the actual excel doc. Run those first. If they work, then try the same thing by reading your own excel docs. Replace what is in the ``read.xlsx`` portion with the name of your file. If it doesnt load the first time, make sure to include the directory (i.e. D:\\Directory\excel.xlsx)

Comment: You of course need to relabel everything, but the functions should work if you plug everything in correctly. Aka dont run the simulated data frames if you already loaded your excel docs.

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: You're very welcome!